# Se inserta dos veces un registro en SQL desde ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

**

```html
<button runat="server" id="cmdSavep" class="btn btn-success" onserverclick="savepago">Guardar</button>
```

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand coman = new SqlCommand();

        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["miconexion"].ToString();
        coman.Connection = conn;
        coman.CommandText = "insert into webpagos (comprobante,formapago,montopago,fechapago,comentario,fecha_audita,user_audita " +
                                ")values(@comprobante,@formapago,@montopago,@fechapago,@comentario,getdate(),@user_audita)";

        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comprobante", cComproba);
        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formapago", cTPpago);
        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montopago", cMontopago);
        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechapago", dtFechaPago);
        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comentario", cComenta);
        coman.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_audita", "XXXY");

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            coman.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Hola, el button esta dentro de un form? puedes poner el codigo de "savepago"?

Comment: ya lo resolvi, por alguna razon habia un conflicto con el control <button>, lo cambia a <asp:Button> y el evento onclick="savepago"